# Powershell Select-All from Word Doc

Tags: powershell

I want to open, then select all of the text from a word document, not any of the properties, formatting, etc. Ihave searched this site and googled it to no end. Basically similar to opening a Word doc and pressing Ctrl-A and assigning the result to a variable.

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.visible = $True
$wordfilepath = "\\symphony1\powershell\Phones\Phone.docx"
$doc = $word.Documents.Open($wordfilepath)
????
$selection" >> $textfilepath
```

Basically a newbie question, but can anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will probably suit your needs.  It creates a new word object, opens your existing file, and pulls the text from it.

```
$filePath = <your file here>
$doc = New-Object -com word.application
$fileToOpen = $doc.Documents.Open("$filePath")
$text = $fileToOpen.Range().text
```

Be forewarned that it will strip out even very basic formatting features such as new lines.  Here's a nice list of other [range members and properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range_members%28v=office.14%29.aspx) that you may find helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Hyper Anthony. I'll have to figure out later how I want to deal with missing new lines, etc but this worked perfectly.